# how to detect otp text in textfield flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, textfield

How can I make auto detect otp text of my textfield in flutter 
I am not getting anything appropriate.
Thanks in andvance.

```
 Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                child:TextField(
                  controller: otpController,
                  maxLength: 6,
                  maxLengthEnforced: true,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: "_ _ _ _ _ _",
                    hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    )

//          border:
//          OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))
                  ),
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 22.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: You need a platform channels to get the OTP from the sms and when you get the OTP update the TextField.

Comment: hey ! @ibhavikmakwana  i am getting the otp from the platform channel but i want when i will enter the last digit of otp it gets recognize and call the api for verify and after verify move to another screen.

Comment: can you please show me the implementation with my text field

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sms_autofill](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_autofill) plugin to automatically fill the [PinFieldAutoFill](https://pub.dev/documentation/sms_autofill/latest/sms_autofill/PinFieldAutoFill-class.html) with the OTP. To listen for OTP code change, you can use the `onCodeChanged` property.